# What is the IccProfChanged window event?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

In SDL2, when a window is created and shown, the first event that bubbles up is `IccProfChanged`. I can't find what that event is - what does it mean?

Comment: Are you talking about [`SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ICCPROF_CHANGED`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/2.0.22/include/SDL_video.h#L178)?

Comment: @genpfault: yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [ICC profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) is the color correction profile. (ICC = International Color Consortium)

Comment: Great! One of the great mysteries resolved!